# MongoDB not inside daterange

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I wanted to query the data which not inside a data range.

I was going through the docs and found `$not` and `$nin`, but I don't know how to apply the `$not` logical operator and the `$nin` operator. I tried to wrap the $not but it throws me an error telling

```
Unknown Top Level Operator: $nin or $not
```

I basically wanted to query get the data inside a date range, I can simply use the `$gt` and `$lt`, but I have a bit complex data.

I have two fields `startDate` and `endDate` and I should use these two fields to query the data based on the data range which the users select.

Support user selects `2017-10-01 to 2017-10-10`, I will have few data where the `startDate` will be less than `2017-10-01` and `endDate` between the date range selected the user (this scenario should not be excluded while querying), similarly I might have a condition opposite the above like, `startDate` inside the date range which user selected and `endDate` greater than `2017-10-10`.

---

I simply wanted to exclude where

```
**`startDate`** and **`endDate`** < '2017-10-01'
```

and

```
**`startDate`** and **`endDate`** > '2017-10-10'
```

My code which I tried,

```
$not: {
    $or: [{
        $and: [
            { "startDate"  : { $lt: begin } },
            { "endDate"    : { $lt: begin } }
        ]
    },
    {
        $and: [
            { "startDate"  : { $gt: end } },
            { "endDate"  : { $gt: end } }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Where `begin` and `end` is a moment object

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

excluding

**`startDate`** and **`endDate`** < '2017-10-01'

and

**`startDate`** and **`endDate`** > '2017-10-10'

This basically means you want to find documents, where startDate and endDate both fall between the selected date range. for this, you can use the following query

```
coll.find({'startDate': {'$gt': begin, '$lt': end},'endDate': {'$gt': begin, '$lt': end}})
```